# Auto refresh view when tab is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tab bar controller, and one of the tabs is my homescreen, and another is a settings page. On the settings page, the user can edit things that are then saved in the NSUserDefaults, but when they return to the home tab, those changes aren't immediately reflected because the view has already loaded. How can I make the view completely refresh when I return to that tab?

Comment: if data is presented on table view or collection view, then you can just reload any one in ViewWillAppear method of controller.

Comment: @TusharSharma The data is displayed in labels. does the ViewWillAppear run everytime the tab is clicked?

Comment: ViewWillAppear gets called every time your view appears.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is only called when your view controller’s view is first loaded—it remains in memory after that, so in general it will never be called again until you create another instance of the view controller.

So Rather than writing the logic in viewDidLoad() that you might have written , write/put the code in viewWillAppear() , this method gets called when ever the view is appeared. So here your NSUserDefaults Values will get set with the new values that will override the existing values.

//Hope I was able to help you out somehow , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when do you want to refresh the view.

1.Do you want to refresh on every time if view is opened.
2.Do you want to refresh the view only when settings are changed?

If it is the 1st one, then you write the refresh logic in viewWillAppear
If it is the 2nd one, then Instead you can add notification whenever user settings are changed.

In the HomeVC add that notification as an observer and update the Labels on that observer method

Code for posting notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"settingsChanged" object:nil];
```

Code for receiving notifications:

In HomeVC ViewWillAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshViews:) name:@"settingsChanged" object:nil];
```

Implement the method on HomeVC

```
- (void)refreshViews:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Received Notification - Someone seems to have logged in");
}
```